# Remove all vowels from a name

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding a Windows Forms application where the user can specify a name and the program will return the name without the vocals. But how does the program understand that if the name contains A, E, I, O, U, Y, then the letters shall be removed.

Comment: "Vocals" meaning "Vowels," I'm guessing?  The program "understands" because you write code to make sense of it!  What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, could you provide some examples?

Comment: Can't you just call string.Replace? Or is it something more complex?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just remove all the vowels (same for upper case) and assign it to the name again:

```
string vowels = "aeiouy";
string name = "Some Name with vowels";
name = new string(name.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out fine, but what does the .ToArray() do? And what do you mean with (name.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)) what does the c do?

Comment: @AwmaN: this is a linq query that selects all the characters from a string where the character is not contained in the vowels string (that is the `Where` part) - the `ToArray()` is putting all these characters in an array and is necessary since one of the string constructor overloads takes a character array as input (but doesn't work with an enumeration)

Comment: While this works for lower case... this solution offers no regard for case insensitive scenarios and it's not entirely straightforward at a glance. The solution I've provided down below offers a two line solution that works regardless of the vowel casing and it's extremely clear up front as to what the code is doing.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older thread but here is a slightly cleaner / more robust way of accomplishing this with a regular expression.

```
string name = "Some Name with vowels";

string output = Regex.Replace(name ,"[aeiou]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 4):

Somebody else will probably offer a regex example, but I would consider a straight forward approach to this:

```
string name = "Flintstone";
     string output = name.Replace("a", string.Empty)
                              .Replace("e", string.Empty)
                              .Replace("i", string.Empty)
                              .Replace("o", string.Empty)
                              .Replace("u", string.Empty)
                              .Replace("y", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Why this abomination of `string.Empty` instead of simply `""`? Do you also define a constant `Integer.Zero` to use instead of `0`?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: No, because `string.Empty` is a system constant and is treated differently than `""`, which instantiates a string instance each time it is evaluated. It is more efficient to use `string.Empty`

Comment: @Cos Irrelevant implementation detail. If there were a real, noticeable difference then the compiler would take care of treating both identical – this is something compilers can do trivially (and do routinely). Nothing to lose sleep over. Certainly nothing to degrade readability over (which a 6x increase in wordiness certainly is).

Comment: @Konrad. I completely disagree, Readability is 100% subjective. I can tell you for a fact when I typed that out I didn't even _think_ about using empty quotes. (for one thing I code in a font that makes empty quotes harder to spot easily). As for the triviality of the difference, I would point out that best practices are such for a reason and **every** best practice write up I have seen say "Use string.Empty" for instance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx. You are (of course) free to do as you choose for your code.

Comment: @Cos “Readability is 100% subjective” – that claim is ridiculous, even without the 100% number. Just because objective best practices are hard to establish doesn’t mean they don’t exist. Avoiding redundant code is well established. The post you are linking to does **not** really say “use string.Empty”. Its message is quite a bit more sophisticated, and it is completely outdated, as has been discussed before on Stack Overflow: both the compiler and the JIT/runtime have evolved tremendously since 2003.

Comment: @Konrad, by all means **you** should continue to do it your way. If you care to site a reference that suggests that I am technically incorrect, by all means post a link and I will read it. You point out that this has been discussed on StackOverflow before, indeed it has, and the takeaway from reading those which I have seen is the same. For **my** part, I will take the 8 year old advise from Brad Abrams until I see something new that suggest that there has been a _relevant_ change in the runtime.

Comment: @Cos Not that I think this will convince you but other programmers have argued that [the best code is no code at all](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/05/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all.html) before me.

Comment: @Konrad, First let me point out that we both digress WAY beyond the scope of the question presented into an interesting, but admittedly trivial, question. Second, the @Jeff Atwood article you present does not support the conclusion Mr. Atwood or you advocate. The question at hand is not "less code" (or _no code_) but merely fewer keystrokes. An inspection of the MSIL produced by empty quotes vs. `string.Empty` the reference to the constant wins out. And, if you know how to work with Visual Studio string.Empty is not even more keystrokes.

Comment: @Cos You’re erecting straw-men. “more keystrokes” was never the argument. The issue is visual clutter: *readability*, not *writability* (as I’ve said before). “An inspection of the MSIL … wins out” – no, it doesn’t. I *don’t care* about the IL (in fact, *if* at all then you need to compare the produced machine code, not the intermediate code). Again, as I’ve said before: if one method is significantly more efficient than the other, then the compiler or the JITter will perform the trivial optimisation of rewriting the less efficient variant into the more efficient one.

Comment: @Konrad, So to summarize you asked why I choose `string.Empty` over `""`.

**1. It is more efficient**, completely true but only minimally so. You have pointed out that simply don't care that it is more efficient because it is only minimally so. 
**2. It is more readable**, This is purely my opinion, but since I am the  one writing the code, I get to decide what I prefer to read. You disagree; by all means you may do it your way.

Since you don't care about trivial efficiencies and other peoples opinions of what makes their own code more readable further discussion would be pointless. Good Day

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse here but `string.Empty` is **not** more efficient than `""` - the later will be interned and create a single string instance. The difference between the two is purely stylistic.

Comment: I cannot imagine that calling string.replace 6 times is more efficient than the RegEx.Replace i've provided down below.

Answer (score 2):

First create a extension method to indentify a vowel that you can reuse wherever you need:

```
public static class MyExtensions{
  public static bool IsVowel( this char c ){
    return new[]{ 'a','e','i','o','u','y','A','E','I','O','U','Y' }.Contains(c);
  }
}
```

Then simply use it like this

```
string test = "Hello how are u";    
string result = new string(test.Where( c => !c.IsVowel() ).ToArray()); //result is Hll hw r
```

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthe an extension method is only valuable if this functionality needs to be used in several places in an application. Good thought, but I am not sure it fits this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main()
        {
            //using HashSet
            //ExceptWith removes the specified elements from the source set. Here, we strip all
            //vowels from the set:

            var letters = new HashSet<char>("Mark");
            letters.ExceptWith("aeiou");
            foreach (char c in letters) Console.Write(c);     // Mrk
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//remove vowels in string in C#

string s = "saravanan";

string res = "";

char[] ch = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' } ;

foreach (char c in ch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {

        if (s[i] == c)
        {
            res = res + "";
        }
        else
        {
            res = res + s[i];
        }
    }
    break;
}

Console.WriteLine(res);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   static string RemoveVowel(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (input[i])
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'o':
                case 'u':
                    sb.Append("");
                    break;

                default:
                    sb.Append(input[i]);
                    break;
            }
        }
         return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string in a textbox and regular expression:using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btndeletevowel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s1;
            string s2;
            s1 = textBox1.Text;
            s2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s1, "[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
            MessageBox.Show(s2);
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str1 = "Hello World";

string str = Regex.Replace(str1, "[aeiouAEIOU]", " ");

Console.WriteLine(str);

Console.Read();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.